# Service WAS was not found on computer '.'. but it's already running

Tags: asp.net, iis, windows-server-2012, windows-server

I have problem with IIS configuration & asp.net website on Windows Server 2012.

I run WAS service in cmd as admin by command:

```
net start was

The requested service has already been started.

More help is available by typing NET HELPMSG 2182
```

but when i try to restart asp.net website i get message:

```
Service WAS was not found on computer '.'.
```

any ideas what is wrong?

Comment: Only Process Model package is installed in Windows Process Activation Service